# Maximize $\sum a_i^3$ for positive $a_i$'s with $\sum a_i=\sum a_i^2=n-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, uvw

> If $n$ positive real numbers $a_i~(1\le i\le n)$ satisfy $\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i=\sum\limits_{i=1}^na_i^2=n-1$, find the maximum or supremum of
> \[M=a_1^3+a_2^3+\cdots+a_n^3.\]

I think the maximum of $M$ is at $a_1=\frac{2n-2}n$, $a_2=a_3=\cdots=a_n=\frac{n-2}n$ and permutations.

For the proof, I thought of the $uvw$ theory. That is to pick three unique numbers, and adjust so that two of them are equal and the cube sum is maximized.

However, such adjustment seem to be endless, so we need a smarter way...

In addition if we can prove that it has got maximum and not only supremum, we could directly inspect the case of maximal, then prove by contraction.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Equal Variable method / Vasc's inequality? This is an immediate consequence.

Comment: @CalvinLin I don't know it. Can you give a solution?

Comment: Go read up on it. See the [original paper](https://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/059_06_JIPAM/059_06.pdf), in particular Corollary 1.4

Comment: That theorem seems a bit strong. It’s clear that the variables are bounded, so you can maximize on a compact set, so the maximum is obtainable. Then, you can show that for $a<b\leq c$ that a solution within $O(t^2)$ of $(a+t(c-b),b-t(c-a),c+t(b-a))$ is better for small $t>0$, so the optimum must be one large value and a bunch of equal small values to prevent contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLOG, assume that $a_1 = \max(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$.

We have
$$a_1^2 + (a_2^2 + a_3^2 + \cdots + a_n^2)
\ge a_1^2 + \frac{(a_2 + a_3 + \cdots + a_n)^2}{n - 1} = a_1^2 + \frac{(n - 1 - a_1)^2}{n - 1}$$
which results in
$$a_1 \le \frac{2(n - 1)}{n}. \tag{1}$$

We have
$$\left(a_k - \frac{n - 2}{n}\right)^2(a_1 - a_k) \ge 0$$
which results in
$$a_k^3 \le \left(2 + a_1 - \frac{4}{n}\right)a_k^2
+ \left(\frac{4}{n} - 1 + \frac{4a_1}{n} - \frac{4}{n^2}  - 2a_1\right)a_k + \frac{(n - 2)^2a_1}{n^2}. \tag{2}$$

Using (1) and (2), we have
\begin{align*}
 M &\le a_1^3 + \left(2 + a_1 - \frac{4}{n}\right)\sum_{k=2}^n a_k^2
 + \left(\frac{4}{n} - 1 + \frac{4a_1}{n} - \frac{4}{n^2}  - 2a_1\right)\sum_{k=2}^n a_k\\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \frac{(n - 2)^2a_1}{n^2}\cdot (n - 1)\\[6pt]
 &= a_1^3 + \left(2 + a_1 - \frac{4}{n}\right)(n - 1 - a_1^2)
 + \left(\frac{4}{n} - 1 + \frac{4a_1}{n} - \frac{4}{n^2}  - 2a_1\right)(n - 1 - a_1)\\[6pt]
 &\qquad + \frac{(n - 2)^2a_1}{n^2}\cdot (n - 1)\\[6pt]
 &= a_1 + n - 1 - \frac{4}{n} + \frac{4}{n^2}\\[6pt]
 &\le \frac{2(n - 1)}{n} + n - 1 - \frac{4}{n} + \frac{4}{n^2}.
\end{align*}

Also, when $a_1 = \frac{2(n - 1)}{n}$
and $a_2 = a_3 = \cdots = a_n = \frac{n - 2}{n}$, we have
\begin{align*}
 M &= \left( \frac{2(n - 1)}{n}\right)^3
 + (n - 1)\left(\frac{n - 2}{n}\right)^3\\
 &= \frac{2(n - 1)}{n} + n - 1 - \frac{4}{n} + \frac{4}{n^2}.
\end{align*}

Thus, the maximum of $M$ is $\frac{2(n - 1)}{n} + n - 1 - \frac{4}{n} + \frac{4}{n^2}$.

Comment: Thanks. Surprisingly, the idea is identical to the standard solution, which was given just now!

Comment: @youthdoo That's find. Usually, I will use equal-variable trick.